# What is the difference between var a = new className() {id = "" , Name = ""} and var a = new className {id="",Name=""}}

Tags: c#, object

What is the difference between while creating object with data

```
className a = new className {id = "foo" , Name = "sass"}
```

and

```
className a = new className() {id="foo",Name="sass"}
```

Comment: The spacing, it won't affect the what the code does, its just code style preference. Oh and if you mean the `()` constructor, the `{}` object initializer will call the constructor as well (so they will not differ)

Comment: No difference. Both of them will do the same thing. Both of them will call the default constructor of the class and set the properties of the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `new className` opposed to `new className()` will make no difference. They both call the default constructor. The spacing difference is irrelevant too.

Both code segments are rewritten by the compiler to something equivalent to:

```
className a = new className();
a.id = "foo";
a.Name = "sass";
```

Answer (score 1):

No difference at all. However you would need the parenthesis if you'd call another constructor, e.g. when there is no parameterless constructor defined:

```
className a = new className(myParameter) {id="foo",Name="sass"};
```

which isn't possible in the first syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Generated code IL is the same in both case:

```
IL_001f: newobj instance void C/ClassName::.ctor()
```

e.g

https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTdwG4CGAJwJ8CAXgIA7AKYB3UhD4BnRQDk+AWynsKASRhiCAIgBmAe1MB9HukMEoBNZoOHFSxVZsBfANxdu1fiEAIwNpORIFZUcpXX1xE3MrVFt7aOdXZSTDHz8CT1zc/CJUeTc03Mpsfxoi5HQABgI9CgBzKWBvRXbvfKrq2iIGhw0Y8jaOro7e/oGIspGWAGVgATAJFoJgNlzuSpnuZvEOnZpp/qK5qIXtvuryM+pezyA===

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. If you have a parameterless constructor, it is still called.
[MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)